# Install MSSQL and .Net Framework 3.5 in Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, installation, dotnet-framework

I have downloaded Windows Server 2012 VHD (Hyper-V VM) and wanna install MSSQL 2012 in it. But it's failing asking for "NetFX3".

Googling about it I discovered it's .Net Framework 3.5 and lots of people had the same problem. Everybody say to use Add Roles and Features Wizard to install it, but also lots of people had problem in this way. Installation files are required.

In this VM I have no access to Internet. Also many reported the same. And the suggestion was to use Win2012 ISO to install it. But I have no ISO, I downloaded VHD.

I downloaded .NetFramework 3.5 offline installation file, but when I execute it I receive an error asking to install it Server Manager, which uses Add Roles and Features Wizard.

I also found the very popular command `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /Source:d:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess` but it requires the ISO.

I extracted offline installation files and pointed it as source, but I'm getting error saying source wasn't found. Both Wizard and command report the same error. As source I used `E:\install\dotnetfx35\wcu\dotNetFramework\dotNetFX35\x64` and all folders below the tree.

I'm now stuck. Installing .Net Framework shouldn't be so troubling. **Anybody knows how I can install it from its offline installation file, without Internet and witout Win2012 ISO?**

Comment: What's E:?  Is that where you mounted the VHD?

Comment: I use 2 virtual disks. C: is the VHD I downloaded from Microsoft with Win2012 installed. D: is DVD drive. E: is another virtual disk I created, it has installers and other files, I'll also install MSSQL in it.

Comment: You don't have WSUS either?

Comment: Can't you just download the ISO and mount it?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh670538.aspx

Comment: I solved it. I couldn't download the ISO because live is blocked in our intranet. But I talked to the department responsible for ISOs and they provided it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I couldn't download the ISO because live is blocked in our intranet. But I talked to the department responsible for ISOs and they provided it to me.